# CDK ls and other commands going irresponsive / stuck while running the cdk app on linux machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cdk

Well i have just started learning AWS CDK. Initially I developed my app on VScode and it successfully synthesized cdk ls was giving me the list of stacks I have in my app. The same set up i did on to linux machine(ec2 instance) but the moment i am hitting cdk ls comand, linux terminal is going irresponsive.

I am not sure where I am getting wrong or there is something else which is required further to be done to run it smoothely onto Linux shell. Programming lang i am using is python(using virtual env)

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this also happen with a minimal app (e.g. `cdk init`)?

Answer (score 0):

Is your RAM of the EC2 instance enough? Usually at least 2GB is required to run CDK.

Comment: Please provide a link that mention the RAM requirements for CDK (if any).

Comment: No, it was just from my experience. I tried running CDK on several EC2 instance types and those with less than 2GB RAM (such as t3.nano or t3.micro) became irresponsive on `cdk ls`.